# Continuously fade a list of thumbnails on top of each other w/ Jquery (only showing 4 at all times?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I'm not exactly sure how to tackle this one.  I've checked out the jQuery "Cycle" plugin, but haven't seen any exmaples of what I really need.

How would you achieve fading in a list of thumbnails from the HTML (maybe something like:

```
<ul id="container">
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link1.com"> <img src="1.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link2.com"> <img src="2.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link3.com"> <img src="3.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link4.com"> <img src="4.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link5.com"> <img src="5.jpg"/></a> </li>
     ...more
</ul>
```

I've created a sample .GIF to explain what i'm trying to do:
 [image]

-There are a total of 4 boxes showing at all times

-Jquery will pull the next image on the list, and fade it into one of the 4 boxes (random box every time).  (image will fade in over the last image in the box).

-This should only happen if there are more than 4 images inside the list.  (stay static if we only have 4)

-Would like to have the ability to add more images via HTML, not inside the JS...

----UPDATE------
Kalle seems to have the correct solution, the only thing missing is the ability to control how many visible thumbnails you see at all times.

Comment: I added some code to Kalle's solution.  He did all the work, so perhaps you can give that bounty to him. http://jsfiddle.net/JDHKn/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I worked 5 (+ 2, ver 1.1) hours on your question. The biggest problem was the switch between two elements. It turns out, that there isn't any "swapping" function.. So I made an alternative.. You cant make this fading transition any better, but it is fairly close your GIF. If you want just to swap them nice and dirty, without any fade.. then that's very easy to make.

Anyways, I composed into a plugin:

### JoeShuffle v1.1

A simple jQuery plugin to shuffle list. Very easy to install and use. Works like any other jQuery plugin. Just add jQuery to your page, include the script with necessary css file. Then, call it to some list and voila! You can change the interval-speed like this: `$('#JoeShuffle').JoeShuffle({intervalSpeed: 2000});`

As of **Ver 1.1** also randomizes the list on the first load and enables to have this script hooked to multiple lists. Also you can set the max. number of displayed elements:
`$('#JoeShuffle').JoeShuffle({displayElements: 4});`.

<sup>**JoeShuffle v1.1 [ [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?8fpe3j49uoul9oy) (33.54 KB) - [View demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/JDHKn/7/) (jsfiddle) ]**</sup>
<sup>**JoeShuffle v1.0 [ [Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?1vn2cxsdbpv9pba) (65.12 KB) - [View demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hobobne/JDHKn/) (jsfiddle) ]**</sup>

**NOTES**

I'm not sure how crossbrowser it is and also it is very dirty and raw plugin. Surely could use some optimization, however it does work.
My examples use colorful boxes, but it really doesn't matter if there are images or whatever in the `li` element.

Some features:

- Remembers the last slot/position, where the swap was made, and wont use it again. Otherwise it will look kinda a weird
- You can set your own custom interval-speed
- Shuffles whatever you put between the list tags. However, you should keep all of them in one size
- **(v1.1)** Randomizes all the elements in the ul list on the first load.
- **(v1.1)** Allows you to set the max. number of elements displayed at once
- **(v1.1)** Enables you to have this script hooked to multiple lists at once

Currently it works like this. Whatever you put inside the `li` elements, it will shuffle them. If you have 5 elements, then it will hide one. And then basically take the hidden element and swap it with some random element. However, I will revisit it in ~15 hours and add the option, that you can set how many are being displayed. So you can actually have 10 elements in the list, but you will only display 4 at the time, there for making the randomization more dynamic.

**Rev 1 notes**

Since you wanted to randomize them on the first load. Then I added the [`rand()` plugin](http://www.afekenholm.se/jquery-rand) to this script. This way it makes the first `hide()` loop very neat and also works as randomizer on the full list..even thought it actually doesn't randomize the list separately..meaning its faster. As I mentioned in the comments inside the scrip, [`rand()` plugin](http://www.afekenholm.se/jquery-rand) by Alexander Wallin, is a must have in your jQuery collection.

As you can see, you can hook it to multiple lists from now on. That and also adding more elements to the list came up a new problem. That the script was loading slow and all the elements would be shown for few ms, on the first load. I fixed the problem, by adding the scripts includes inside the `<head>` and not after the contents of the page. This way the scripts get loaded before the elements.. and that means everything is smooth.

Though I have no idea what happens, if the `displayElements` option is set lower, then the actual elements count inside the list. Best avoid such situations.

Also if you noticed that the elements get floated together in CSS. You could also use `display: inline-block;`, but `inline-block` isn't very crossbrowser, so I used `float`. This however means, that under the elements you should have `clear: both;` in some form.. Or maybe even some wrapper around the list.

Comment: Hey Kalle, with the option to set how many are displayed at once I will choose your answer as Bounty!

Comment: Also, is it possible to START with a random selection from the "pool"?

Comment: @Joe: I will add the display_filter shortly. With the second comment, do you mean, that it would shuffle the elements on the first load?

Comment: Yeah!  Possible to do?
$('#JoeShuffle').JoeShuffle){randomInit: true});

Comment: I'm working on the revision of the script. Have better ideas, but too drunk to make them happen right now. So tomorrow. However, I'm not sure about the shuffle on load..as it might get too buggy and possible display a white page for few ms..also it could lead to layout problems. This could only be possible, if all the elements are originally hidden, but that wont look good either. I don't recommend this feature.. it would even be better to randomize the order via PHP, on the first load at least.

Comment: Ahh, good call on randomizing with PHP.  I can do that no problem.  Let me know how the script goes, and I'll find a way to donate a couple bucks towards your next drunken adventure.  ;)

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying your code, @Kalle -hope you don't mind, I'm not claiming it as my own.  Have yourself another beer, because the bounty is yours!  http://jsfiddle.net/JDHKn/4/

Comment: @skabbes: Hehe, not bad. I didn't know about the `filter()` function, so thanks for that example. Though at the end I went with my own idea..also added some other functions and tweaks. PS: You have a bug related to the settings with `number` and `numShowing` not matching ;) And for the record, I had few beers more^^

Comment: @Joe: I edited my question, added the features you wanted. Even got the randomizer feature on the first load.. Though, it doesn't actually shuffle them in a separate loop, but does it inside the hide extra elements on load loop -- meaning it is optimized to be faster, then with a separate loop. No need for PHP anymore. Definitely check the .rar packs demo .html, because the scripts placement is very important now. Otherwise you will get a buggy-effect, that delays the elements hiding step for few ms. Anyways, I'm very happy with the result.

Comment: Wow, perfect.  I'm obviously not a great programmer but I know what clean code looks like.  Bounty to you!

Comment: Ty^^ I will give you a little guarantee-time too. So if anything is funky or you got some questions about the plugin, then get the e-mail from my website and I'll give you a hand :)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/MbQrw/

This should cover the basic stuff you're needing. It's not very elegant and stuff like initialization is missing, but the main technique is shown.

Comment: This is very close to what I need- however is there a simpler way to do it with just jQuery? (easier for me to understand and modify)- and add new items via the HTML and not within the JS?

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/VETmf/

The concept is similar: grab an element in a list, do an action, move onto the next element, and if it is the end; loop back to the beginning.

```
$('input').click(function (e) {
    toggleImg($('div img:first'));
});

function toggleImg(I) {
    var nextI = I.next();
    if (nextI.length == 0) nextI = $('div img:first');
    I.toggle('slow', function() {
        toggleImg(nextI);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Now this doesn't pre-populate the divs with images and it doesn't handle getting the link code in with the images as they display but you can handle that with just a little extra work.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var maxDisplay = 4;
var displayBox;

$(document).ready(function() {

  StartShow();

});

function StartShow() {
    var interval = 5000;
    var slideShowID;

    slideShowID = setInterval(Gallery, interval);

}

function Gallery() {
  var nextImage = $("#container li.selected").next().length;
  displayBox = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxDisplay);
  if (nextImage > 0){
    $("#container li.selected").removeClass("selected").next().addClass("selected");
    imgSrc = $("#container li.selected").children().attr("src");
    if(imgSrc != null) {
      $("#" + displayBox).fadeOut('slow', function() { $("#" + displayBox).css("background-image", imgSrc); }).fadeIn();
    }
  }
  else {
    $("#container li.selected").removeClass("selected").siblings(':first').addClass("selected");
    imgSrc = $("#container li.selected").children().attr("src");
    if (imgSrc != null) {
      $("#" + displayBox).fadeOut('slow', function() { $("#" + displayBox).css("background-image", imgSrc); }).fadeIn();
    }
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="container" style="display: none;">
    <li class="thumbnail selected"> <a href="www.link1.com"><img src="1.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link2.com"><img src="2.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link3.com"><img src="3.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link4.com"><img src="4.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link5.com"><img src="5.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link6.com"><img src="6.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link7.com"><img src="7.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link8.com"><img src="8.jpg"/></a> </li>
    <li class="thumbnail"> <a href="www.link9.com"><img src="9.jpg"/></a> </li>
</ul>


<div>
 <div id="1"></div>
 <div id="2"></div>
 <div id="3"></div>
 <div id="4"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nft5a/6/) with much more in the way of settings but i'm only posting the sinmplest part of the code here. I didn't use images just `<li>` elements with background colours.

```js
var floor = Math.floor;
var random = Math.random;
function randomindex(num, style) {
    return floor(random() * num);
};
$.fn.continuousFade = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        "max_visible": 4,
        "delay": 2000, // in ms.
        "speed": 500, // in ms.
        "style": "normal"
    }, options);

var children = this.children(".thumbnail").css("display", "");

for (var i = 0; i < settings.max_visible; i++) {
    children.eq(i).css("display", "inline-block");
}
function fadeone() {

        var visibleChild = this.children(".thumbnail:visible").eq(randomindex());
        var hiddenChild = this.children(".thumbnail:not(:visible)").first();

        var parent = this;

        visibleChild.before(hiddenChild);
        hiddenChild.css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "opacity": 0,
            "display": "inline-block"
        }).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, settings.speed, function() {
            hiddenChild.css("position", "");
            parent.append(visibleChild.css("display", "")); // Need to put this one at the end so it will get displayed again last.
        });
        setTimeout(function() {
            fadeone.call(parent);
        }, settings.delay);
    }
    fadeone.call(this);
};
```

The jsFiddle has options for other ways of getting a random image and the ability to change the settings and it shows more children.
*Current jsfiddle:-* http://jsfiddle.net/Nft5a/42/

Comment: Im sorry mate, but that is seriously bugged.

Comment: @Kalle I'm sorry you need to be more specific. It seems to work for me fine.

Comment: you fixed it now, but revision 8 was bugged and showing up extra box.

Comment: @Kalle Sorry I never saw an extra box. And I'm not sure that I changed any of the plugin logic that would change that behaviour. Maybe I should look into it as it maybe be an issue with the timeout. EDIT: new one: http://jsfiddle.net/Nft5a/15/ hopefully no more intermittent bug. (heisenbug anyone?)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Nft5a/8/ It is bugged, [check this screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/163/screenshotstudiocapturevx.png/). I actually had the same problems at first. It appears that you fixed them on the newer versions. Oh no wait, the 15# has a bug too, it starts hiding the children. Also it switches them some what weirdly. Great script, dont get me wrong, just that it kinda isnt complete.

Comment: FF3. IE8 is okay. Also IE8 it switches them very very smoothly. But, in FF3 it doesn't look even remotely that good and also that extra box bug. Though, in IE the swap looks very cool. If you could make it the same in all browsers, then this would be better then my solution.

Comment: @kalle I've only got IE and chrome so I can't test that out. Thanks for the help Ill have to update this when I get ff3.

Comment: Get firefox for sure. Firefox is everything todays world ^^

Comment: @James, I wish there was an option to award points for the 2nd best answer- as I was able to use your solution for a demo (have since gone with Kalle's as final version).  

The only problem I encountered was in Google Chrome (16.0.883.0 Canary OSX) that if you open a new tab, and then switch back to the tab that contains your script- it adds an extra element.  

I've noticed strange behavior with switching tabs with scripts running in Chrome before, only browser I noticed that does it.

Comment: And actually now that I look again, yours fulfulled something that Kalle's script doesn't do:   Fade the new element OVER the old element.  His version shows a split second blankness before the new element fades in.

Comment: @Joe the old one doesn't fade out so it shouldn't show any blankness. It gets its display removed and the default is set to `display: none`. The tab issue might just be a jsFiddle thing? It has a `setTimeout( ...` on it at 13 seconds it changes the third set of elements showing you that it can be changed while running.

Comment: @Joe There is an odd css bug happening here. http://jsfiddle.net/Nft5a/42/ has a working version.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but maybe this will work for your defining # of images problem:

what I would do involves doing a bit of math, but say I want 4 pictures showing at all times, and they are 50px each with no margin or padding (margins and padding is where the math really comes into play) then I would put them in a div that is 200px wide (4*50) with overflow set to hidden in the html (where your list should be with the images). this is explained a bit more in this question: "http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/making-an-infinite-jquery-carousel/" 
hope that helps.